# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} matching urls when they start with but doesn't end with some multiple substring

Tags: regex, .htaccess, regex-negation

I have a list of url like this.

```
/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Hambu-logo.png
/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Anesa-logo.png
/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Rock-logo.png
/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Blue-logo.png
```

Using RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} I'd like to rewrite to another site when %{REQUEST_URI} starts with **/wp-content/uploads/** and doesn't end with one of these 2 strings **Hambu-logo.png** or **Anesa-logo.png**

I've tried a lots of different expressions but it doesn't work. What I do wrong with the Negative Lookahead?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/.*(?!(Hambu-logo.png|Anesa-logo.png))$
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads(.*)$ https://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads$1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/.*(?!(Hambu-logo.png|Anesa-logo.png))$
> RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads(.*)$ https://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads$1 [R=302,L]
> ```

The `.*` before the negative lookahead consumes the rest of the string and the negative lookahead *assertion* always fails.

You could instead use a negative lookbehind:

```
^/wp-content/uploads/.*(?<!(Hambu|Anesa)-logo\.png)$
```

However, this can be simplified. You don't need a negative *lookaround*. Just use a negated expression in the *condition* (mod_rewrite syntax). There's no need to match the URL-prefix in both the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and *condition*.

For example, in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(Hambu|Anesa)-logo\.png$
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/ https://www.test.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The above matches all URLs that start `/wp-content/uploads/` and do not end with either `/Hambu-logo.png` or `/Anesa-logo.png`. The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the expression so it is successful when it does not match.

Since you are redirecting to the same URL-path at the target you can just use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable and avoid the capturing subpattern in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

---

Alternatively, you create another `.htaccess` file in the `/wp-content/uploads` subdirectory and the rule can be further simplified (no need for the `RewriteCond` directive):

```
RewriteRule !(^|/)(Hambu|Anesa)-logo\.png$ https://www.test.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```